# Can't access array values in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I send an array of values to my node server to be written to a log file.

My $.ajax post works at the client side. At the back-end, I print the array to the console, but when I try to write it to the file using the code below, i get a blank output in the log file.

```
function log(req,res)
{
  var list = req.body;
  console.log(list);

  for(var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++)
  fs.writeFileSync("./log.dat", JSON.stringify(list[i]) + "\r\n");
}
```

The array is a collection of JSON objects like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO4s3.png) on the console.

Side Note: I can write to the file if I remove JSON.stringify and [i] though.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I did this and I get "undefined" in my log file.

```
try {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    fs.writeFileSync("./log.dat", list[i] + "\r\n");
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error writing Metadata.json:' + err.message)
}
```

I've deduced it's something to do with the loop and the array. 
I can't reference the array by index.

My ajax req code:

```
var items = {logs: foghorn_items};
      path = server + "Foghorn/log";
      $.ajax({
      url: path,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: items,
      success: function (data){
        alert('Logs sent to file');
      }
);
```

**UPDATE**

For some reason the loop doesn't work with list.length and req.body.length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function log(req,res)
{
  var list = req.body;
  console.log(list);

  for(var i = 0; i < list.logs.length; i++)
  fs.writeFileSync("./log.dat", JSON.stringify(list.logs[i]) + "\r\n");
}
```

Try the above one

Comment: can you show the body data? is that above link in your question?

Comment: Yes, that's body data that's getting printed from console.log(list)

Comment: what is printing in console which i have posted?

Comment: what is printing in console now?

Comment: The same screenshot I posted.

Comment: It's still blank again

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva probably you should change `var list = req.body` to `var list = JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: @ItsMyLife I'm already using a bodyParser. If i use JSON.parse I get an error

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva what did you get from line `console.log(typeof req.body)` and `console.log(typeof req.body.logs)`

Comment: @ItsMyLife Object and undefined respectively

Comment: @ItsMyLife okay I fixed it. It was because I was using req.body.items and not req.body.logs.

Answer (score 1):

Use try/catch, to show error:

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync("./log.dat", JSON.stringify(list[i]) + "\r\n");
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error writing Metadata.json:' + err.message)
}
```

Comment: what access rights to the file? and check the path to file

Comment: See the last line of my question

Comment: Thought about it, but could not to check it in my side

Answer (score 0):

use appendfile method

```
fs.appendFile("./log.dat", JSON.stringify(list[i]) + "\r\n",function(err){   
});
```

when you are using **writeFileSync**, in log file it shows last value written.
which might be blank.

Comment: i get "undefined" for list[i]. But if i do console.log(list), it prints all the values

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++)
  fs. appendFile("./log.dat", JSON.stringify(req.body[i]) + "\r\n",function(err){   
});